# Is there a formal way to aggregate the Web of Science Categories?

Tags: bibliometrics

I'm doing network analysis at the level of the author using data from `Web of Science`. As you might know, the column, `WC` has information about the [`Web of Science Categories`](https://images.webofknowledge.com/images/help/WOS/hp_subject_category_terms_tasca.html), which are around 250 disciplines. I was wondering if there is a proper way to aggregate them, for instance, using the `22 disciplines` from the [`Essential Science Indicators`](http://ipscience-help.thomsonreuters.com/inCites2Live/8300-TRS.html).

Answer (score 2):

Both *Web of Science Categories* and *Essential Science Indicators* are journal-level categorizations (with some reclassification of papers in multidisciplinary journals going on in *Essential Science Indicators*), with the difference that each journal can belong to multiple *Web of Science Categories* but only to one *Essential Science Indicator* category. This usually means that individual papers within a journal (at least within the same issue or year) will be assigned to the same *Web of Science Categories* (one or many) and also to the same *Essential Science Indicators* category. By mapping the *Essential Science Indicators* categories of journals (found [here](http://ipscience-help.thomsonreuters.com/inCites2Live/filterValuesGroup/researchAreaSchema/esiDetail.html)) onto papers you will therefore automatically get an aggregation.

However, since journals (and papers) can have multiple *Web of Science Categories* attached to them (without any prioritization of what is the "main" category), you cannot have a simple one-to-one mapping between them, at least not without some further work.